# On understanding how to compute the Big-O of code snippets

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I understand that simple statements like:

```
int x = 5; // is 1 or O(1)
```

And a while loop such as:

```
while(i<); // is n+1 or O(n)
```

And same with a for a single for loop (depending). 
With nested while or for loop such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){ // this is n + 1
for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){ // this is (n+1)*n, total = O(n^2)
}
```

Also anytime we have a doubling effect it's log_2(n), tripling effect log_3(n) and so on. And if the control varible is being halved or quarted that's also either log_2(n) or log_4(n).

But I am dealing with much more complicated examples. How would one figure these examples out. I have the answers I just don't know how to work them out on paper come an examination.

Example1:

```
for (i = 1; i < (n*n+3*n+17) / 4 ; i += 1)
System.out.println("Sunshine");
```

Example2:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
if ( i % 2 == 0) // very confused by what mod would do to runtime
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
System.out.print("Bacon");
else
for (j = 0; j < n * n; j++) 
System.out.println("Ocean");
```

Example3:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10000 * n: i *= 2)
x += 1;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is bounded by the term `(n*n+3*n+17)` and therefore should be `O(n^2)`.  The reason this is `O(n^2)` is because the largest, and therefore dominant, term in the expression is `n^2`.

The second example is a bit more tricky.  The outer loop in `i` will iterate `n` times, but what executes on the inside depends on whether that value of `i` be odd or even.  When even, another loop over `n` happens, but when odd a loop in `n^2` happens.  The odd case will dominate the running time eventually, so example 2 should be `O(n^3)`.

The third example iterates until hitting `10000*n`, but does so by doubling the loop counter `i` at each step.  This will have an `O(lgn)` performance, where `lg` means the log base 2.  To see why, imagine we wanted to reach `n=32`, starting at `i=1` and doubling each time.  Well we would have 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32, i.e. 6 steps, which grows as `lg(32)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I think I am beginning to understand. What I originally thought was that we follow where the control variable and what happens to it. So inspect what's happen to the passed in variable 'n' and see how it's contorted throughout the code. But now I am reading that 'i' effects things to? How so? So which one should I examine, the 'n' control variable or the 'i' incrementing variable?
Thanks agin

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense in general.  We need to figure out how the running time of each example will scale, as a function of n.

Comment: As a scale of n. So when we look at the code we are thinking to ourselves how does n scale in relation to the code. So we are focusing on that n, could be 10 could be 100000 so if 'n' isn't present in a section of code it has no effect on n. So if i is say multiplied like this: for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i*2);this is going to SCALE n to 0(log_2(n)) because of how 'i' is being changed. So it's like 'n' is the test subject and how we set up 'i' changes the test environment.